# d3 graph adding additional label to xaxis

Tags: d3.js

I am adding an additional value label to d3 graph xaxis, but it gets cropped by the general size of `svg`

[image: cropping]

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

.selectAll(".tick")
    .data(data)
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 30)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Is there a way to force recalculation of `svg` height?

Comment: put the creation of the svg in a function, passing through the width and height. then call this function again with the new width and height

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  In the classic [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) `height` includes a margin for the axis: `height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;`, where the SVG is height is `.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)`?  If you follow this pattern just increase `margin.bottom` to have enough space for the axis and labels.

Comment: @Mark thanks Mark, I fixed my problem with margins